# MySQL - using float in function

Tags: mysql, function, floating-point

I have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `calculateSalary`(workDays INT, daysWorked INT, salary DECIMAL) RETURNS DECIMAL DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE handSalary DECIMAL;
DECLARE fullSalary DECIMAL;
SET fullSalary = salary * daysWorked / workDays;
SET handSalary = fullSalary * cast(0.86 as decimal(11,2));
RETURN handSalary;
END.
```

MySQL shows my an error on `0.86` which says "86 is not valid, expecting EOF, etc.", what should I do? How to use float numbers?

Comment: Please add full error message NB there is no issue with the published code assuming you set delimiters?

Comment: I don't understand your comment about float numbers - can you be more specific. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uooTWgTyi6CzLnf3h2mPrn/0

Comment: Yes, I was using point as delimiter, didn't notice this detail, thanks

Comment: Change `DECIMAL` to `DECIMAL(11,2)`  (four times) in your function definition, and in the DECLARE statements.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you get:

```
mysql> select calculateSalary(30,20,242.5);
+------------------------------+
| calculateSalary(30,20,242.5) |
+------------------------------+
|                          139 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Notice the 1 warning!

`show warnings` will say: `Data truncated for column 'salary' at row 1`

Changing `DECIMAL` to `DECIMAL(1,2)`:

```
DROP FUNCTION `calculateSalary`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `calculateSalary`(workDays INT, daysWorked INT, salary DECIMAL(11,2)) RETURNS DECIMAL(11,2) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE handSalary DECIMAL(11,2);
DECLARE fullSalary DECIMAL(11,2);
SET fullSalary = salary * daysWorked / workDays;
SET handSalary = fullSalary * cast(0.86 as decimal(11,2));
RETURN handSalary;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

will output:

```
mysql> select calculateSalary(30,20,242.5);
+------------------------------+
| calculateSalary(30,20,242.5) |
+------------------------------+
|                       139.04 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice: no warning!